# How to pass to an intent if Permission request is denied

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an Action that integrates with Dialogflow which as part of the conversation requests access to the user's location.
[image: Dialgoflow screenshot]

This is fulfilled via a webhook:

```
app.intent('actions_intent_PERMISSION', async (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
    if (!permissionGranted) {
        app.intent('actions_intent_PERMISSION - no', (conv, params) => {
            conv.ask('sad face, you said no to my permission request!');
    });
    // conv.ask(`Ok, no worries. I'll have to figure out how to get your postcode. follow-up intent I suppose`);
    } else {
        conv.data.postcode = conv.device.location.zipCode;
        conv.ask(`Ok great - please give me a minute, I have to get data from a few different places.`);

     //use postcode to make some other API calls
    }
});
```

Everything is fine when the user gives permission but when they don't give permission I would like to pass off to an intent that asks for their location manually ('what is your postcode/zipcode?').

As per the screenshot I tried creating a followup intent to `actions_intent_PERMISSION` called `actions_intent_PERMISSION - no` but this causes the app to crash.

What is the best way to pass the conversation to another intent is the value of `permissionGranted` is `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't quite make sense the way you've asked it. Intents represent *what the user has said* and not what you do with it - that is what your webhook does in an Intent Handler. There is nothing (technically) stopping you from replying to the user asking for their zip code by just replying differently.

If you want users to be able to trigger some Intents if they have given permissions, and other Intents if they have not, you can set a different [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) for each. Then you would set some Intents to only be triggered if the "permitted" context was set, and others only if the "notpermitted" context was set.

However, you have a non-technical problem to consider. If they aren't giving you permission to get their location, why would they tell you their location? It also is likely that the reviewers would reject it, saying that you should be getting location information through the provided API.

Comment: Many thanks @Prisoner.   Re the non-technical problem, the use case is primarily that the location that they are currently in is not the location they want to find out about (so Permission to get current location is irrelevant).  I was thinking of having an intent *Provide Zipcode* that I would route to if `if (!permissionGranted) {.....}` was true.  Thanks for the info on Context, seems like it could be very useful

Comment: Hope it helps. If you find an answer useful, upvoting and/or accepting it are always appreciated.